# Restrict only two selections in a multi selection drop down in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a dropdown in my excel sheet and I wanted to add multiple items from that dropdown into the cell. I was able to do that and now it functions as shown in the picture below:
[image]

I also wanted the users to only be allowed to choose two items from the entire list of items from the dropdown. The users can choose any two but also only two. I was not able to do that. Can someone help me? here is the code I used.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$C$8" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
If Target.Address = ("$C$8") Then
        If InStr(1, Target.Value, "5", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly does the code do, and what is failing? Personally I think it's better to paste the code as text, so that we can experiment with it.

Comment: I cannot seem to add the code because of some error.
Here is where I got the code from
https://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-multiple.html

The code works but I want to restrict the users to only be able to select only two items from the dropdown. the drop-down has 5 items but the user should be able to select only two items (any two).

Comment: I edited the code and turned it into texts

Comment: a) What kind of Dropdown: Form Control? Active X Control? A dropdown on a Userform? Validation? b) How it the code related to you question? What is it doing? Why did you add it to the question?

Comment: @FunThomas The code is for a validation dropdown which enables me to add multiple items to the cell from that dropdown. I wanted to add something else to the code and that is to only allow two selections from the list of items in the dropdown. My current dropdown has 5 items in it I want the users to only be able to select any two from those list.

Comment: What is the point of hiding row 9?

Comment: That is for if the user selects an item called custom, another cell will appear for the user to add custom inputs

Comment: I edited my post to make my question clearer

Comment: Oh Wow! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a hard time to understand your question and also the code. It is a very uncommon behavior that you have a data validation dropdown that allows to *add* something into that cell. This results in a very strange user experience

- When I select an entry from the list, there is no way to remove it again except clearing the cell.
- When I select something and then press Ctrl+Z (undo), Excel cannot undo my change.
- When I select more than the limit (2) number of entries, the change is not accepted, without further notice.
- When I enter something manually in that cell and the limit of 2 entries is already reached, my changes will not be accepted.
  For me as a user, that strange behaviour would drive me mad. As a clever user, I will find out sooner or later that I can Paste something into that cell. That will delete your data validation - If you want to go down that road, you must add logic into the trigger that prevents this.

That said, I cleaned up your code and added a check for a maximum number of entries - the change itself is rather easy, before adding the entry, it is checked how many NewLines are already in the value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const MaxEntries = 2
    
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String
    
    If Target.Address <> "$C$8" Then GoTo Exitsub
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then GoTo Exitsub
    If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub
        
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
    If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
    ElseIf InStr(Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 And countCharsInStr(Oldvalue, vbNewLine) + 1 < MaxEntries Then
        Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
    Else
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
    End If
    
    Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = InStr(Target.Value, "5") > 0
    
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Public Function countCharsInStr(s As String, c As String) As Long
    countCharsInStr = (Len(s) - Len(Replace(s, c, ""))) / Len(c)
End Function
```

Comment: Better answer than mine. Quick question, why `"$K$3"`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Was from my personal test. Adress of course must reflect OPs needs

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was still able to select more than 2 items from  my Dropdown menu.

Comment: And you have debugged your code to see why it was possible? For me, it worked, but of course I don't have your setup.

Comment: I edited my post to make my question clearer

Comment: @FunThomas Not yet, let me check

Comment: @FunThomas It Worked!

This is exactly what I needed... Thanks for providing me your solution

Answer (score 0):

The code structure doesn't make much sense to me, so I rearranged it.
My solution is a separate function anyway, so it should work either way.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$C$8" Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
    ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
        GoTo Exitsub
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 And Not CountLines(Target) > 1 Then
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
            Else
                Target.Value = Oldvalue
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If InStr(1, Target.Value, "5", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Public Function CountLines(Target As Range) As Double
Dim H1 As Double, H2 As Double
With Target
    .WrapText = False
    H1 = .Height
    .WrapText = True
    H2 = .Height
End With
CountLines = H2 / H1
End Function
```

Since the added values are separated by a new line, counting how many values there are can be a bit tricky. One way would be to measure the height of the cell, which is what the function does.

We call this function to check the number of lines as we are adding new values. I merged it with the `If` checking for duplicates.

Comment: See answer from FunThomas for a very simliar, yet more elegant sollution.

Comment: I edited my post to make my question clearer

Comment: FYI you can also allow the user to re-select an item to remove it from their selections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65205311/excel-vba-multi-select-drop-down-list/65209501#65209501  If you do this then they can choose a different option after first removing one of their original choices.